# What's a simple way to create 100 .txt files with 1 random number in each of them

Tags: bash, random

I asked a similar question before, but the answers that I got weren't exactly what I was looking for.
I want to create 100 .txt files with 1 random number in each of those files and assign them permissions based on the number inside the file.
I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r -f .txt
touch {1..100}.txt
r=$RANDOM
```

to create new files each time the script is ran and assigned random number to "r".
How do I paste a different number into each file. I'm not sure if I need to use echo or shuf to do it.

After that I need to check if the random number is divisible by 2 and 3 and give the files permissions based on that.
I intend to use:

```
chmod 000 {1..100}.txt
if ((r % 2 == 0))
then echo chmod +rw {1..100}.txt
elif ((r % 3 ==0))
then chmod 777 {1..100}.txt
else chmod +w {1..100}
```

but I'm not sure if that works either.

Comment: Do you want all 100 files share the same random value or a different random for each file?

Comment: @WalterA different random number number in each file

Answer (score 3):

> What's a simple way to create 100 .txt

Iterate over files and output the numbers.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)); do
  echo "$RANDOM" > "$i.txt"
done
```

Comment: So if I use
`
#!/bin/bash
rm -r *.txt
for ((i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)); do
echo $RANDOM > "$i.txt"
done
`
to create 100 files with random numbers.
Can I use
`
num=$((cat $i.txt))
chmod 000 "$i.txt"
if ((num % 2 == 0))
then
chmod +rw "$i.txt"
elif ((num % 3 == 0))
then chmod 777 "$i.txt"
else chmod +w "$i.txt"
fi
`
to check if the number is divisible by 2 and 3 and assign permissions to the files

Comment: When you want to add logic with the ramdom value, do something like `random="$RANDOM"; echo "$random" > "$i.txt"; ((random%2==0)) && echo "Even"`

Comment: doesn't that make the number fixed? I want there to be a different number in each file, but if I paste a different number in each file I'm not sure how to check if the number is divisible by 2 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `chmod` can be done with code similar to the code in your question (changing it for 1 file each time and adding a `fi`). I skipped the `chmod 000` and assign the correct mode at once.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)); do
  r="$RANDOM"
  echo "$r" > "$i.txt"
  if ((r % 2 == 0)); then
    chmod 666 "$i.txt"
  elif ((r % 3 ==0)); then
    chmod 777 "$i.txt"
  else
    chmod 222 "$i.txt"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so when I run the script it prints out all the files with the changed permissions?

Comment: You can do `ls -l {1..100}.txt` at the end or an `echo` after each `chmod`.